# multiline textview, start editing on the second line?

Tags: java, android

I have `EditText`-views with two lines (`android:lines="2"`). The first line has a constant `String` like "Name:" for instance, that will not be changed. I want to programatically get the text that the user enters on line two from the app. 
The two solutions i have is to just use two single line `EditText`s or a more cumbersome alternative is to get the string from the `EditText` and remove the constant `String` from line 1 as I assume that a multi line `EditText` still acts as a single line, meaning not every line is unique.
So my question is, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Each and every line in a multiline edittext is differentiated using the escape character '\n'. So get the string using 
   edittext.getText().toString()    and find '\n' to get the number of lines(cheat: \n = 0 : 1 Line , \n = 1 : 2 Line, \n = 2 : 3 Line). Now to get the 2nd line substring from 1st \n to end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best solution is that you use a TextView for the defined text and an EditText for the user input